# Ubuntun 18.04 Bluetooth active but applet display inactive

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, applet

I am facing an issue pretty annoying concerning bluetooth. I cannot connect any device by bluetooth because in the applet it is always shown as disabled [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pullP.png)

But the fun part is that when I go into command lines, the status of my bluetooth is on :

```
> sudo service bluetooth status

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-12-18 11:37:38 CET; 4min 28s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1156 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1156 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

déc. 18 11:37:37 kevin-G501VW systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
déc. 18 11:37:38 kevin-G501VW bluetoothd[1156]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
déc. 18 11:37:38 kevin-G501VW systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
déc. 18 11:37:38 kevin-G501VW bluetoothd[1156]: Starting SDP server
déc. 18 11:37:41 kevin-G501VW bluetoothd[1156]: Version mismatch for sixaxis
déc. 18 11:37:41 kevin-G501VW bluetoothd[1156]: Bluetooth management interface 1
```

And with another command to check if bluetooth was blocked :

```
> rfkill list all

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
50: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have no idea what causes this, it happened several times before but rebooting was working fine until today. I rebooted several times in a row but still not working. Do you have any ideas guys ?

Thanks for helping me :)

EDIT : 
As requested as it may help :

```
> lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3fd Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c084 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: the edit is done @Pilot6 !

Comment: I have no solution. Now at least we know the BT hardware.

Comment: No problem, thank's for trying. Hope someone has one

Comment: I have the same problem, and I think that is connected with the missing in my computer of WiFi device. Mine is a old Ethernet card without WiFi, and the applet constantly says it's in airplane mode.

Comment: Mine is a laptop with working WiFi. With a day of rest and a reboot this is working clean right now but i fear facing that issue again